# Inserir arquivo html via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olha eu gostaria de carregar a parte "head" do meu html em apenas um arquivo e depois chamado no html atraves do java script.

Hoje eu tenho seguinte:

Header

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo onde gostaria de inserir o header

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso inserir o mesmo via javascript pois vou usar o mesmo header em varios lugares.

Eu pesquisei na internet e me retornaram algo como

```
 $("#header").load("index.html");
```

Porém eu não vou inserir em uma div e sim no html em si.

Comment: Precisa ser especificamente em html? seria mais simples fazer isso com php :D

Comment: infelizmente sim Alvaro, não vamos usar nada no projeto além de de JS/HTML E CSS;

Comment: Vc pode tentar com `<object data="html/stuff_to_include.html"> 
    Your browser doesn’t support the object tag. 
</object>` mas só vai funcionar se os arquivos estiverem em um servidor. Ou vc pode usar um iframe

Comment: O ideal era carregar apenas o `<head></head` e não o `<!DOCTYPE html>` e a abertura do `<html>`.

Comment: Outra coisa é que Ajax só funciona em ambiente de servidor.

Comment: Você devia era usar uma linguagem de programação, qualquer uma, para montar esses HTMLs para você. Como faz o [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/), por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Deixe em seu arquivo externo apenas o conteúdo interno do `<head>` e utilize o `<link rel="import" href="">` para fazer o include.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>       
        <link rel="import" href="/head.html">
    </head>
</html>
```

[Referência](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/#link-type-import)

Comment: Esse para ai funciona local, ou tem que por no server?

Comment: você quer dizer outro domínio?

Comment: Pode ser tb rss. to perguntando pra saber se da pra testar localmente e incluir um html dentro de outro dessa forma. É só por curiosidade mesmo

Comment: Sem um servidor o browser pode bloquear

Comment: Seria interessante colocar um link sobre a [compatibilidade nos browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=imports). Mas minha dúvida é se não precisaria ter algum script pra manipular o conteúdo do import. Funcionaria como  um include do PHP? Pergunto por causa [deste artigo](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/#usingcontent).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) do JavaScript para criar uma tag `<head>` antes do `body` e puxar via Ajax o conteúdo do outro arquivo e mandar para dentro dessa `<head>`, mas é preciso fazer umas considerações:

Quando você **não** insere a tag `<head>` diretamente no HTML, o navegador automaticamente corrige e insere `<head></head>` no documento. Com isso, ao inserir de forma dinâmica uma tag `<head>`, o documento irá ficar com tags `<head>` duplicadas (uma criada pelo navegador e a outra inserida via `.insertBefore`).

> Aí você pode perguntar: "*por que criar um `<head>` se o navegador já
>   cria?*". Como eu não sei se **todos** os navegadores fazem isso, seria uma
>   forma de precaução.

Coloque no arquivo `head.html` apenas o conteúdo da `<head>`, sem as tags `<!doctype>` e `<html>`. Isso porque a tag `<!doctype>` define o tipo de documento da página e não pode ser inserida de forma dinâmica. Com isso a estrutura da `index.html` teria que ser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
   <!-- AQUI SERÁ INSERIDA A <head> -->
<body>
   CONTEÚDO
</body>
</html>
```

E do arquivo `head.html` apenas o conteúdo da `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
...
<link href="arquivos/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Outro ponto é que se pretende usar Ajax, só irá funcionar em protocolo HTTP, ou seja, em um ambiente de servidor.

Considerando os pontos acima, uma solução usando o Ajax do JavaScript (sem necessidade do jQuery) é sugerida abaixo:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var novo_head = document.createElement("head"); // cria o nó <head></head>
   var htMl = document.querySelector("html"); // seleciona o elemento html
   htMl.insertBefore(novo_head, htMl.childNodes[0]); // insere o nó <head></head> antes do body

   var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); // cria o objeto XHR
    http.open("GET", "head.html"); // requisita a página .html
    http.send();
    http.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(http.readyState == 4){ // retorno do Ajax
         var head = document.querySelectorAll("head"); // seleciona os <head>
         // insere a resposta no primeiro <head>
         // o índice [0] significa o primeiro elemento
         // o replace é para remover as tags <head> e </head> da resposta
         head[0].innerHTML = http.responseText.replace(/<\/?head>/g, "");

         // remover a segunda tag <head> do DOM se existir duas,
         // para que não haja tags duplicadas
         if(head.length > 1) head[1].remove();
      }
   }
});
```

Como o código já cria a tag `<head>` com `document.createElement("head")`, seria interessante que o arquivo `.head.html` não tivesse também as tags `<head>` e `</head>`, ou seja, apenas o HTML interno da `<head>`. Assim você pode excluir do código o `.replace` em `http.responseText.replace(/<\/?head>/g, "");` deixando apenas `http.responseText;`.

### Se for usar jQuery

Se for usar jQuery, pode usar a função [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) enviado o retorno para a tag `<head>` criada com o método `.before()`.

No caso do jQuery, não é preciso se preocupar com duplicidade da tag `<head>`, porque mesmo que a tag seja adicionada pelo navegador, o jQuery não a duplica.

A estrutura da `index.html` seria (carregando o jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
   <!-- AQUI SERÁ INSERIDA A <head> -->
<body>
   CONTEÚDO
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(function(){

      $.get("head.html", function(data){
         $("body").before("<head></head>"); // insere o <head> antes do <body>
         data = data.replace(/<\/?head>/g, "");
         $("head").html(data); // insere o retorno do Ajax dentro da <head>
      });

   });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Como dito, o `.replace(/<\/?head>/g, "")` é para retirar do retorno as
>   tags `<head>` e `</head>`, mas mesmo que o retorno venha com essas
>   tags, o navegador corrige, porém coloquei o `replace` por precaução,
>   pois não sei se todos os navegadores fazem essa correção automática. Mas o ideal é que o retorno venha sem essas tags, conforme dito também.

Answer (score 0):

Sua aplicação é HTML e javascript puro? não vai utlizar nada server side?
se for, crie o arquivo header. com o conteúdo separado do header o o adicione via INCLUDE da linguagem que estiver utilizando,

Conselho, geralmente se deixa o Header e o Footer na pagina, e troca seu conteudo,
assim você criaria um "layout.html" com a estrutura.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
       e aqui você coloca os conteudos das suas paginas
    </body>
</html>
```

pode facil dai utilizar o jquery pois vai ter a tag Body, 
pode fazer

```
<body>
 $("#header").load('paginaativa.html');
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer isso!

```
<head id="header">

</head> 


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
    },0); });
</script>
```